# The absolute div won't scroll it is still static

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am trying to place a box along side each image on my webpage that will scroll down with the page but only inside the confines of the post/image, like can be found at [memecenter](http://www.memecenter.com/), but i am having some difficulties.

I have set the parent div (post) to position relative and the child div (scrolling box) to position absolute, and they are nested within each other in the html but the child div wont scroll it still stays static on the page.

See code here:

```
.parent {
position: relative;
width: 613px;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 10px 0;
border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
.child {
    position: absolute;
    width: 46px;
    height: 100px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

and html:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "top" and "left" values.

Css Part:

```
.parent {
    position.parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 613px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
    }

.child {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 46px;
    height: 100px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
    float: left;
}:
```

Html part:

```
<div class="parent">
    <img src="img.png" width="100px">
    <div class="child">This is image description</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried this but it the box still stays static and wont scroll with the page like the example website.

Answer (score 0):

Css :

```
    .parent 
    {
        background-color:Blue;
        position:fixed;
        width: 150px;
        height:200px;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 10px 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    .child {
        background-color:red;
        position: absolute;
        width: 460px;
        height: 220px;
        float: right;
        margin-left:150px;
        overflow:scroll;

    }
```

and html:

```
   <div class="parent">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
    </div>
```

Please find a working fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/Victor_AJ/8GS7b/13/

Comment: i have been trying to find a working fiddle all day and have gotten nowhere.

Comment: It is working fine in the above mentioned fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/Victor_AJ/8GS7b/13/

Comment: It still is staying static for me in the fiddle, even if i change the length to a long way down it still wont scroll down the side along the length. Im not wanting the parent div to be fixed, only the child div see this fiddle.... http://jsfiddle.net/8GS7b/23/

Comment: Bump ... I think everyone is misunderstanding the question because none of these fiddles are showing me anything at all. none of the boxes are floating and scrolling with the page. all im after is something that is fixed but within a boundary and not the page itself. If this is only possible with javascript, can someone please provide me with a js edit i can try out?

Answer (score 0):

CSS :

```
   .parent {
        background-color:Blue;
        position:fixed;
        width: 70%;
        height:100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 10px 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
        overflow-y:scroll;
        overflow-x:hidden;
    }
    .child {
        background-color:Grey;
        position: absolute;
        width: 30%;
        height:100%;
        float: right;
        margin-left:70%;
        overflow:hidden;
     }

 And Html :
    <div class="parent">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
    </div>
```

Find a Fiddle Here [Working EX](http://jsfiddle.net/8GS7b/26/)